# how do we run existing angular application on nodejs without express or any other framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, node-modules

I am new to angularjs and node.js. I have my existing angular application which is run in node using node_modules (and also using gulp tasks for dev, wiredep, jshint).
And now I want convert it to nodejs to run the app as node but it would be has its angular and it template. I don't know how to do this.